# I need help calling a method from my MVC controller and returning its return value(int) using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

First and foremost, this is not a school project. I am currently creating an ASP.NET MVC project and I am new to javascript. Currently I have a google chart set up that I would like to display on the webpage. That is working fine but instead of using hard-coded numbers, I am wanting to get the SUM of specific numbers from a database. I have written a function in my controller already that performs the SQL query and returns the SUM as an int value.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("graphs")]
public static int getMonth(int monthNum, int eventTypeId)
{
    int identity = -1;
    using (SqlConnection con =
        new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PilotDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
        )
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd =
        new SqlCommand(
                    "SELECT SUM(count) FROM DailyAggregate WHERE MONTH(created_on) = @monthNum AND event_type_id = @eventTypeId AND YEAR(created_on) = YEAR(getdate())",
                    con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthNum", monthNum);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventTypeId", eventTypeId);
                if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works without issues and successfully returns an int when called. The problem is that I am trying to call this method in my cshtml index file (where the graph is created) instead of hard-coding in values. I have read about web methods and ajax but am not really getting a good grasp on it at least not in the context of what I am trying to do. Can someone point me in the right direction as far as a solution to my problem or at the least some relevant documentation to my problem? Also if there is a better way of going about this that would be appreciated as well. Here is my current variable in the cshtml file:

```
  var Monthly = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Monthly Data in (Year)', 'Login Count Per App', 'Failed Login', 'Password Change'],
            ['January', 1500, 234, 234],
            ['February', 1950, 234, 234],
            ['March', 2300, 234, 234],
            ['April', 2300, 234, 234],
            ['May', 1500, 234, 234],
            ['June', 234, 234, 234],
            ['July', getGraphs(7, 8), getGraphs(7, 9), getGraphs(7, 11)],
            ['August', 234, 234, 234],
            ['September', 234, 234, 234],
            ['October', 234, 234, 234],
            ['November', 234, 234, 234],
            ['December', 234, 234, 234]
        ]);
```

And here is my ajax function:

```
function getGraphs(monthNum, eventtypeId) {
$.get({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/weasel/graphs",
    data: { monthNum: monthNum, eventTypeId: eventtypeId },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        return response; 
    },
    failure: function () {
        alert('bad request');

    }


});
}
```

Comment: You would be a lot better off having a SQL query and controller action that returned that entire array as JSON instead of making repeated calls to get individual numbers.

Comment: @PaulAbbott thanks for the tip! That seems way more efficient and I will definitely look into that! Any idea why the current version I have wouldn't be working though? I don't think I am setting up the ajax function correctly any documentation on ajax that you would recommend for this situation?

Comment: Well, for starters, your controller action is attributed `[HttpGet]` but you're using `type: "POST"` in JS; use `type: "GET"`.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Thanks for the tips!